# How to hide my custome shipment method based on custom product attributes in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute

I'm a very new to Magento2.
I'm stuck with display the new shipment option show/hide.

I have created a new shipment method programmatically and name it "**Same Day Delivery**"
and also I have created a Product Attribute programmatically and name it "**Same Day Delivery Available**: (Yes/No).

I would like to add the restriction on the Checkout page - If all items in CART have (Same Day Delivery Available as **Yes**). Then display the new shipment option or hide them in the shipment selection section.

Two things i have done,

1. Shipment method programmatically
2. Product Attribute programmatically

I need shipment option have to show based on product attribute.

Here is my coding:**strong text**
https://github.com/balajimrv/app

Kindly help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your model career file "collectRates " method you can getAllVisibleItems and you can add condition if for any of product has "Same Day Delivery Available" is not available then you can simply "return false;" it will not call your shipping on cart/checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get cart items in your **collectRates** function and return false if your attribute value is **No**. you can get your attribute **Same Day Delivery Available** value by product id easily.

Comment: get attribute by product id is very old and bad practice. nowdays magento giving us feature for ``catalog_attribute.xml`` for achive this kind of requirement.

Comment: could you send the full code? please.... help me